# For Loop to rename objects in a data frame (+ ignore NA) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame that contains a column with binary variables (pointed or broad). To do my calculations I need to replace them with 0 or 1. I want to write a for loop which is doing this for me.

My code:

```
binary_To_Number<-function(df)
{
 for(i in df)
   {
      if(i=="pointed")
        {
          i<-1
        }
      else if(i=="broad")
        {
          i<-0
        }
      else if(is.na(i))
        {
          print("NA")
        }
      else
        {
          
        }
    }
}

binary_To_Number(town$shape)
```

I tried to use this piece of code. My first problem with it is that I don't know how to save the results. So my code is changing the i temporarily but won't save it in the df. I know that you can create an empty storage vector to store results in it, but can I replace the variable in my df immediately?
The second problem is that my code stops and gives me an error message if it comes to an i which contains NA.

```
Error in if (i == "pointed") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is there something I can do about it or do I need to replace the NA with a placeholder first?

Comment: The advantage of R is that there are built in ways to modify a vector already, e.g. `town$shape[town$shape=="pointed"] <- 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use dplyr (ensures 0 for not pointed):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    isPointed = as.integer(tolower(shape) == 'pointed')
  )
```

Output:

```
    shape isPointed
1 Pointed         1
2   broad         0
3 pointed         1
```

The dataframe I used:

```
df <- data.frame(
  shape = c('Pointed', 'broad', 'pointed'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```